# Adding before and after an item

Tags: c#, arraylist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k82jo.png)How to add an element to the ArrayList C #. I need to add an element before and after a keypad search item.

```
                case 5: string caut = Console.ReadLine(); Angajat t = listaAngaj.Find(x => x.Nume == caut);
                    int k = listaAngaj.IndexOf(t); listaAngaj.Insert(k + 1, new Angajat()); Console.WriteLine(k);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    string caut1 = Console.ReadLine(); Angajat t1 = listaAngaj.Find(x => x.Nume == caut1);
                    int k1 = listaAngaj.IndexOf(t1); listaAngaj.Insert(k1, new Angajat()); Console.WriteLine(k1);
                    break;
```

That's what I did in the List

Comment: It's not clear. An ArrayList returns an `object`. Because you get an object typed as `Angajat`, it must be a `List<T>`. You are showing two cases (5 and 6) taken out of context (where is the `switch`?). In case 5 you insert after, in case 6 before. Where is exactly the problem?

Comment: this code is in "List"

Comment: You are already inserting objects after and before. Why are you asking how to do it?

Comment: I need to write it in "arraylist

Comment: these codes display an error at "Find" in "arraylist"

Comment: `listaAngaj.Insert(k + 1, new Angajat());` inserts after. `listaAngaj.Insert(k1, new Angajat());` inserts before. More precisely: it inserts at k1 and pushes the  existing entries starting at k1 to the end.

Comment: Please, show the whole code with the declaration of `listaAngaj`.

Comment: `   class Angajat
    {
        public string Nume, Prenume, functie;
        public DataC dataNas, dataAng;
        public int stagiu;
        public Angajat()
        {`

Comment: Possible causes: 1. `listaAngaj` is declared as `ArrayList listaAngaj` instead of `List<Angajat> listaAngaj`. 2. `x.Nume` is a `int`, but `caut` is a `string`. Get an `int` with `int n = Int32.Parse(caut);`

Comment: Please edit your question and complete it, so it becomes compileable. I still don't see the declaration of the list `listaAngaj`. What the error say?

Comment: The point is that `listaAngaj` is neither an `ArrayList` nor a `List<T>`, but a `LinkedList<T>`. Use a `List<T>` instead. Its easier to handle. If you still want to use a `LinkedList`, you must loop through it to find the right item and then use `AddBefore` or `AddAfter`. See: [LinkedList<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I hope you use utorrent for legitimate purposes.